# Inserting nodes into a trie data structure

Tags: c++, performance, trie

I have a recursive algorithm that inserts nodes into a trie data structure but it seems to be running not well and takes over 10 mins to complete on a data set of about 1 million. All nodes contain a syllables to a phrase all of the syllables are then inserted into the trie to allow for searching in a binary fashion to attain \$n\log(n)\$ runtime.

As for my performance goal for the insertion, I'm looking for \$O(m\log(n))\$ where \$m\$ is number of phrases and \$n\$ is number of syllables in each phrase.

I am also aware of the stunning lack of memory management.

Recursion:

```
void Trie::recursiveInsert(Node* starting,stack<string>* words){
    if(starting->getNumberOfChildren() == 0 || starting->getChildren()[words->top()] == 0){
        Node* temp = new Node(words->top());
        starting->appendChild(temp);
        this->numberOfNodes++;
        words->pop();
        if(!words->empty()){
            recursiveInsert(temp, words);
            return;
        }else{
            temp->setEndOfWord(true);
            return;
        }

    }
    starting = starting->getChildren()[words->top()];
    words->pop();
    if(!words->empty()){
        recursiveInsert(starting, words);
    }

}
```

Supplementary `Node` class:

```
Node::Node(){
    this->value = "";
    this->numberOfChildren = 0;
    this->endOfWord = false;
    this->vowel = false;
}

Node::Node(string data){
    this->value = data;
    this->numberOfChildren = 0;
    this->endOfWord = false;
    this->vowel = false;
    if(isdigit(data[data.size() - 1 ])){
        this->vowel = true;
    }
}

string Node::getValue() const{
    return this->value;
}

map<string, Node*> Node::getChildren(){
    return this->children;
}

string Node::childrenToString(){
    std::map<string, Node*> v = this->children;
    string done = "the Children of \'" + this->getValue() + "\' are ";
    for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++ ){
        done = done +  it->first + " ,";
    }

    return done;
}

void Node::appendChild(Node* node){
    this->children[node->getValue()] = node;
    this->numberOfChildren++;
}

int Node::getNumberOfChildren(){
    return this->numberOfChildren;
}

bool Node::isVowel(){
    return this->vowel;
}

bool Node::isEndOfWord(){
    return this->endOfWord;
}

void Node::setEndOfWord(bool value){
    this->endOfWord = value;
}
```

Comment: You might want to fix the indentation in Trie::recursiveInsert().

Comment: @pacmaninbw  i fixed the indentaion